# Real vs complex integral for taking exam

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

In future exams for my students, I want to ask them to solve an integral using Cauchy's (extended) integral formula, real methods (hopefully, trigonometric substitution and/or partial fractions), and compare their results.

I have searched a lot, I invented some exercises, but I am not satisfied. Could you suggest some integrals?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my first complex analysis i was asked to compute this integral with both real and complex methods,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2+\sin\theta}\;d\theta$$

Also
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2+1}\;dx$$
could be a good question because using residue theorem it has a double pole at $x=i$ and using real methods is not so difficult